# How do I assign values based on content of columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a new column with a numerical value assigned based on whether pet1 contains the word 'cat' or the word 'dog'

```
    pet1           
0   dog             
1   dog;cat;rabbit  
2   cat;dog         
3   manbearpig      
4   hippo
```

I would like the end result to be as follows:

```
    pet1            points
0   dog             5
1   dog;cat;rabbit  5
2   cat;dog         5
3   manbearpig      0
4   hippo           0
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the string method [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for this.
Starting from this dataframe:

```
In [96]: df
Out[96]:
             pet1
0             dog
1  dog;cat;rabbit
2         cat;dog
3      manbearpig
4           hippo
```

You can check if each element contains the substring 'dog':

```
In [97]: df['pet1'].str.contains('dog')
Out[97]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: pet1, dtype: bool
```

and then multiply by 5 to end up with your desired result:

```
In [98]: df['pet1'].str.contains('dog') * 5
Out[98]:
0    5
1    5
2    5
3    0
4    0
Name: pet1, dtype: int32
```